# Initial migration to database that contains data + correct schema?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

What is the recipe for automatic migrations to a database that has not been used with the application yet (has no __MigrationHistory) but contains the 100% correct schema plus data which must be retained? I ran into this situation twice in migration projects to code first. I have been using

```
update-database -script
```

in this situation and just deleted all the DML from the script only keeping the __MigrationHistory create + insert statement. Seems to work, but will this come back and haunt me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO it's correct solution.

EF uses data from the `__MigrationHistory` table to compare the model defined in your application with the schema of the database. Because your database already contains the correct schema, you just need to add `__MigrationHistory` table with the migration metadata.